# After changes, do I need to rebuild the project in Android Studio before to run it?

Tags: android-studio

When I modify some files in my project, like .xml, .java, etc.. I must build the project manually  or I just need to click on "run project" to make an automatic rebuild?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After every change, the project should be rebuilt in order to run with the new changes. This however will be done automatically when you pres the "run project" button. So no need to worry about that.

Also if you want to make sure that there are no errors left in the code you can press the "compile code" button first to find out. If you don't do this and there are errors in the code when you press the "run project" button, the program will inform you of this. So compiling the code is not necesarry but it is usefull to know this.